# Ruby override Enumerable method

Tags: c, ruby, monkeypatching

I'm trying to overwrite a method on the Enumerable module like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def collect(&block)
    puts 'collect'
    super
  end
end
```

(Note this is a trivial example).

Theoretically, when I call `collect` or `map`, Ruby should use my overridden version, right? But it's not. It always uses the built-in Enumerable method. Is it because `collect` is actually `enum_collect` and complied with the source?

```
[1,2,3].map(&:to_s) # never prints anything
```

Yes, I'm aware that Monkey-Patching is bad, etc, etc, and I'm aware there are alternatives including subclassing, etc, but I want to know if it's possible to overwrite a built-in C function with Ruby.

```
Enumerable.class_eval do
  def collect(&block)
    puts 'collect was class_eval'
    super
  end
end
```

```
eigen = class << Enumerable; self; end
eigen.class_eval do
  def collect(&block)
    puts 'collect was eigen'
    super
  end
end
```

```
module Enumerable
  def collect(&block)
    puts 'collect was opened up'
    super
  end
end
```

```
Array.send(:include, Enumerable)
```

and pretty much every combination thereof.

PS. This is Ruby 1.9.3, but ideally I'm looking for a solution that would work on all versions.

Comment: The first question is, why? Why not write a class, mix in Enumerable (`include Enumerable`), then define `each` to do what you want? That way *all* the enumerable methods behave the way you want for that class, and you can inherit from that if needed.

Comment: "I'm aware there are alternatives including subclassing, etc, but I want to know if it's possible to overwrite a built-in C function with Ruby." I want to change the way map works on all Enumerable objects. I didn't say anything about `each`...

Comment: run this, and see that it's *all* about `each`: https://gist.github.com/4410424. It doesn't answer your question specifically, but it allows you to consistently change Enumerable behaviour.

Comment: I understand that, but that doesn't help answer my question. I want something to apply to all Arrays, not a subclass that includes a custom Enumerable.

Comment: There is also a problem with aliasing. I am not sure which of `map` and `collect` aliases to which, but when a method `foo` is aliased to `bar`, and you change the definition of `bar`, then `foo` will be left with the old definition unless you alias `foo` to `bar` again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that Array defines its own [`collect` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-collect) rather than using Enumerable's:

> **collect {|item| block } → new_ary**
>   **map {|item| block } → new_ary**
>   **collect → an_enumerator**
>   **map → an_enumerator**
>
> Invokes *block* once for each element of `self`. Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block. See also `Enumerable#collect`.

So you can monkey patch `Enumerable#collect` all you want but `Array` won't care because it doesn't use `Enumerable#collect`. You'll have better luck if you monkey patch `Array#collect`:

```
class Array
  def collect
    #...
  end
end
```

You'll want to patch `Array#map` as well or just patch `map` and let the alias take care of `collect`.

Note that `Array#map` is implemented in C so the C part had nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid. It's incredibly misleading that `Array` include `Enumerable` and then implements its own methods for those... I was getting read to write a custom C extension!

Comment: I'd guess that `Array` does a lot of the `Enumerable` stuff itself for performance reasons, arrays do have a special structure that iteration can take advantage of after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over many different types of objects in Ruby using the same set of methods. For example, you can use the includes? method to iterate over Arrays and Hashes to see if they include a specific object, and similarly use the map method to transform them. You might think each method implements these methods themselves, but you'd be wrong.

In Ruby, these types of methods are implemented in the Enumerable module. If your class implements the each method and includes the Enumerable module, your class will respond to a whole host of messages involving collections, including iterating, mapping, searching, etc.